# React native app showing dependencies error every time when building the app to apk although dependencies are up to date what to do?

Tags: android, node.js, git, react-native, npm

I have a react native app that is always getting an error every I build an android app where install independencies in expo always return error I have attached a document with the error returning from expo please help???

[image]

[image]